Applying for Android EMM: Your staff numbers haven't been updated for the new program year
When I applied for EMM Membership (for Android Management API's) I got following error post submission:

When I press on [Add Staff Totals] it shows another dialog where nothing happens on any keypress:

There should be no errors or In case errors are there there should be a clear way of fixing these errors as of now given dialogs are very much non functional.
